# Dynamically detect number of options from string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to detect dynamically via regex the options from a question with different number of options. Questions could have options until b, c, e or f, g.... current example is until d.

```
1. Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)
a. data link
a. network*
a. physical
a. session
```

PHP - What I tried. This detects only for 4 options, if I add a 5th one or 6th one, or if I remove one it won't work.

```
$textarea = preg_match_all('#\d+\.\s(.*)\s*[a-zA-Z]\.\s(.*?)\s*(.*)\s*[a-zA-Z]\.\s(.*?)\s*(.*)\s*[a-zA-Z]\.\s(.*?)\s*(.*)\s*[a-zA-Z]\.\s(.*?)\s*(.*)\s*#i', $textarea, $matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1. Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)
a. data link
a. network*
a. physical
a. session
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => data link
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => network*
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => physical
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => session
        )

)
```

REGEX ONLINE

http://regexr.com/3en2b

Comment: Trying to do all with a single regex isn't a good approach. Since each question and option starts in a newline, read the string by line. Building a generator may be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with a generator function:

Lets say you have this string:

```
$txt = <<<'EOD'
1. What is your name?
a. Theresa
b. Mike
c. Jugurtha
d. I don't know

2. What is your favorite animal?
a. Rabbit
b. Dog
c. Cat
d. Poney
e. Unicorn
EOD;
```

The generator function:

```
function getQuestionAnswers($fh) {
    while (false !== $line = fgets($fh)) {
        if (preg_match('~^(?:(?<Qno>[0-9]+)|(?<Ano>[a-z]+))\. (?<content>.*)~', $line, $m)) {
            if ($m['Ano']) {
                $result['answers'][] = ['no' => $m['Ano'], 'content' => $m['content']];
            } else {
                if (isset($result))
                    yield $result;

                $result = [
                    'question' => [
                        'no' => $m['Qno'],
                        'content' => $m['content']
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($result))
        yield $result;
}
```

How to use it:

```
$fh = fopen('data:text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($txt), 'rb');

foreach (getQuestionAnswers($fh) as $qas) {
    printf("Question number %d with %d answers\n", $qas['question']['no'], count($qas['answers']));
}

fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple regex: `#(.?)\.\s(.*)(\n|$)#im`:

```php
$textarea = <<<LINES
1. Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)
a. data link
b. network*
c. physical
d. session
e. test1

2. Question 2
a. link
b. net*
c. phys
d. ses
e. tst
LINES;

$questions = preg_split('#\n[\\n]+#', $textarea);

echo "Questions: \n";
print_r($questions);

echo "--------------------------\n";

//if($found = preg_match_all('#(.?)\.\s(.*)(\n|$)#im', $textarea, $matches)) {

foreach($questions as $question) {
    //if($found = preg_match_all('#((.?)\.\s(.*)(\n|$))|(?=\s*^\s*$)#smx', $question, $matches)) {
    if($found = preg_match_all('#(.?)\.\s(.*)(\n|$)#im', $question, $matches)) {
        echo "Q ".$matches[1][0].': '.$matches[2][0]."'\n";

        for($i = 1; $i < $found; $i++) {
            echo "  A {$i}: '".$matches[1][$i]."', '".$matches[2][$i]."'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Questions: 
Array
(
    [0] => 1. Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)
a. data link
b. network*
c. physical
d. session
e. test1
    [1] => 2. Question 2
a. link
b. net*
c. phys
d. ses
e. tst
)
--------------------------
Q 1: Which two OSI model layers have the same functionality as two layers of the TCP/IP model? (Choose two.)'
  A 1: 'a', 'data link'
  A 2: 'b', 'network*'
  A 3: 'c', 'physical'
  A 4: 'd', 'session'
  A 5: 'e', 'test1'
Q 2: Question 2'
  A 1: 'a', 'link'
  A 2: 'b', 'net*'
  A 3: 'c', 'phys'
  A 4: 'd', 'ses'
  A 5: 'e', 'tst'
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to have multiple questions in one string, then you should first split the empty lines of the string and have all the questions stored in an array like this:

```
$questions = preg_split('#\n[\\n]+#', $textarea);
```

See my updated code above for a complete example.

Comment: there are multiple questions, so this is good for one question